# How to Kill an activity on back button pressed

Tags: java, android

One of my activity displays a down count timer by the help of `CountDownTImer()` method. The `onFinish()` method of the Down count timer is displaying a toast to tell the user that the time has elapsed. When it reaches 00:00. The issue is when I press the back button before the time elapses I still get the toast message even if the activity is not visible.
So, I try to kill the activity on the back button pressed by overriding the `onBackPressed()` as follows, but still, the toast is displaying even if the activity is invisible.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
     super.onBackPressed();
     this.finish();
}
```

Comment: what toast is showing , can you share your code.

Comment: add your entire code

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't cancel `CountDownTimer()` :

```
public void onBackPressed(){
     yourCountDownTimer.cancel();
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks. So the finish() method doesn't kill the activity?

Comment: no, the finish() method finished the activity right away, but the process of  CountDownTimer() still working